# Mime Content-Type name is gibberish

Tags: .net-4.0, mime

What follows is a snippet from a raw email:

Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
        name="ï¿½ë°¶Ã³ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ä´ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ë¼ï¿½Ó¦ï¿½ï¿½.xls"

I have attempted to parse the name as a Base64 encoded string, but it fails that.  What could it be?

I have seen the same text for a Content-Disposition filename:

Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="ï¿½ë°¶Ã³ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ä´ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ë¼ï¿½Ó¦ï¿½ï¿½.xls"

Neither of these will pass the validation in the System.Net.Mime constructors for ContentType and ContentDisposition objects.

For the record, the attachment is a legitimate xls file.

Comment: This sounds like an ASCII parsing issue to me. You might want to take the name into an array of chars or ascii chars and look at the values. Maybe it's in hex and the http string is reading it as decimal, etc.

Comment: How did you create this? It doesn't matter if the *file* is a legitimate xls file, the name and filename parameters refer to the file *name*. Are you setting the content of the xls file as the file name?

Comment: I didn't create this and I am not setting anything.  It came to me in an email, and I'm just trying to understand it, because, as I said, the constructors for ContentType and ContentDisposition reject it.